# Organizing the Model Structure and Controller Structure - Laravel

Tags: laravel

The Admin assigns roles and permissions for employees. How should the structure of the models be like

1 Admin
 - EmployeePermission
 - EmployeeRole
or

2 Employee
 - Role
 - Permission
Also the If Admins are incharge of creating Employees, i assume that the controllers should be organized as below mentioned

Admin
- EmployeeController.php
- EmployeeRoleController.php

Comment: My suggestion is to use [ENTRUST](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) to easily handle all roles & permissions. This is an awesome package. I use it every time.

Comment: @Sand Of Vega
I am using laravel 5.6. Will that be a problem ? 
Also at the moment i prefer to do it my way rather than using a package

Comment: It's okay. I am using it in 5.7.